# How to position Bootstrap button to right of nav tab?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap's tab component and I'm having trouble getting the blue **Log In** button flush to the right side of the `nav-tabs`. I tried all kinds of things, but obviously I'm not understanding why it won't get positioned where I want.

Here's an image of what I am trying to do:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<section class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs pt-5">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Data</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Log In</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/auov8ety/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

simply give `ml-auto` to the button

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs pt-5">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Data</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Log In</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0fep392h/

Comment: For Bootstrap 5 you have to use `ms-auto` instead of `ml-auto`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use class `ml-auto` (Read [Bootstrap Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/) for more info) on the `nav-item` that wraps the button:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs pt-5">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Data</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Log In</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the time to help! THanks!

Comment: @redshift you are welcome, however, you can upvote at least since I was the first to answer and you accept an answer similar to mine that was posted after.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to seperate the button from the list and use `flexbox` with `justify-content: space-between;`

Code sample:

```css
section.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   <section class="container pt-5">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Data</a></li>
      </ul>
      
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Log In</button>
    </section>
```