# Bootstrap 4 nav tabs component with dropdown justified at the end

Tags: bootstrap-4

As per official Bootstrap 4 [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#using-dropdowns), adding dropdowns to `Nav Tabs` component is a matter of adding a little extra HTML.

Following is the code from the doc. I re-adjusted the `nav-item` elements to put the `dropdown` sub-component at the end of `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` list.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>


  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </li>


</ul>
```

My concern is how to **justify** the sub-component `dropdown` at **the very end** of the `Nav Tabs` component ? How to apply `justify-content-end` class to `<li class="nav-item dropdown">` element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use auto margin **`ml-auto`** and `dropdown-menu-right` to make the dropdown items align properly...

https://codeply.com/p/9FTNF7Jloa

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Also see: [How to position Bootstrap button to right of nav tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54368986/how-to-position-bootstrap-button-to-right-of-nav-tab)